# how to get src of changing image and store into php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, html

The file is called `Step1.php`. The html codes just show a picture with three words below to change the image src using javascript.(The image changes perfectly fine)

I am able to successfully bring the src over to the next page using session. It echo's `images/rose.png`

The problem is that when the image is changed (via the onclick function),

on the next page it doesn't seem to echo the new image src, but still echos `images/rose.png`.

Html:

```
<img id="flower" src="images/rose.png" />

<table>
<tr>
<td><div onclick="rose()"> rose </div></td>
<td><div onclick="dove()"> dove </div></td>
<td><div onclick="lily()"> lily </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
function O(obj) {
if (typeof obj == 'object') return obj;
else return document.getElementById(obj)
}

function rose(){ flowersrc = 'images/rose.png';}
function dove(){ flowersrc = 'images/dove.png';}
function dove(){ flowersrc = 'images/lily.png';}

O("flower").src = flowersrc;
```

PHP:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
session_start();
$html = file_get_contents('Step1.php');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$tag = $dom->getElementById('flower');
$flowersrc = $tag->getAttribute('src');

$_SESSION['flower'] = $flower;
?>
```

PHP of second file:

```
 <?php
    header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
    session_start();
    $flower = $_SESSION['flower'];
    echo $flower;
 ?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use PHP? It seems more logical to store this in a cookie; which could easily be done with javascript?

Comment: You may missing `echo '<img src='.$_SESSION['flower'].'"/>';` try..

Comment: it's okay the img doesn't come out i just want the right img src string to be echo'd out. Additionally, if i use cookie will it be able to store the changing src?

Comment: Update the cookie when you change the source.

Comment: Do you have any sites to reference for me to learn this? It really is much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you save the wrong variable to session, try changing `$_SESSION['flower'] = $flower;` to `$_SESSION['flower'] = $flowersrc;`

Comment: problem still persists

Comment: And as @meavo says you could save the image state to cookies using javascript, e.g. `document.cookie ='name=value; expires=Sat, 18 Jan 2014 18:47:11 UTC; path=/'`. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html for more information